# Using SUDS with HTTPS and setting location

Tags: python, soap, https, suds

I am using SUDS to call SOAP using this code:

```
client = Client("https://xyz.rwth.de/SecuredDataService/SecuredData?wsdl",location="https://xyz.rwth.de/SecuredDataService/SecuredData",cache=None)
```

For a HTTP request, a request similar to the above code works (without the location part in the above request and the correct HTTP URL), but for HTTPS it fails and give the below error.

> DEBUG:suds.wsdl:reading wsdl at:
>   https://xyz.rwth.de/SecuredDataService/SecuredData?wsdl ...
>
> DEBUG:suds.xsd.sxbasic:Import:0x1025f5710, importing
>   ns="http://secured.services.xyz123.org/",
>   location="http://xyz.rwth.de:7070/SecuredDataService/SecuredData?xsd=1"
>
> DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening
>   (http://xyz.rwth.de:7070/SecuredDataService/SecuredData?xsd=1)
>
> ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /XYZ12/index.html/

I am getting a `urlopen error [Errno 60] Operation timed out`

Basically the log file shows that the `location` argument is NOT getting used, instead the location specified in the WSDL file (which is: http://xyz.rwth.de:7070/SecuredDataService/SecuredData?xsd=1) is getting used. Why is that so, even when the SUDS documentation clearly states: `location: This overrides the service port address URL defined in the WSDL.`?

Edit: After adding the `cache=None` the correct location is getting called, and the whole WSDL is getting printed in the log files. However after that, the same error (as mentioned above) is printed in the log files.

Comment: adding `Cache=None` in the Client call, actually outputs the whole WSDL in the log files :)
However, at the end it again gives similar 
`error:DEBUG:suds.xsd.sxbasic:Import:0x1022a10d0, importing ns="http://secured.services.xyz123.org/", location="http://xyz.rwth.de:7070/SecuredDataService/SecuredData?xsd=1"
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (http://xyz.rwth.de:7070/SecuredDataService/SecuredData?xsd=1)
ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /XYZ12/index.html/`